# Get method returns XML and JSON

Tags: java, xml, json, rest, get

If i do this:

```
@GET
    @Path("/users")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String users()
    {
        String users = null;
        ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

        try {
                userList = new UserManager().getUsers();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
        users = gson.toJson(userList);

    } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return users;
    }
```

my GET method just retuns the information in JSON. 
But I want it to returns XML too? Something like `@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what framework you're using here, but it doesn't particularly matter - you can't return both formats (in a sensible way) in the same request.  The `Content-Type` header only exists once for a given response, so it cannot be both `application/json` and `application/xml`.

The common idiom here is to allow for a `GET` parameter which specifies the format in which the client would like the data to be returned - ala `http://example.com/path/to/rest/data?type=JSON` or `http://example.com/path/to/rest/data?type=XML`.

Comment: But just like I convert the information to JSON (`users = gson.toJson(userList);`), I don't have to convert it to XML too?

Comment: The point here is that you can only return one type at a time.  You will still have to convert to whatever type you want to return, but you can't return them both in the same reply.  Perhaps there's a second question about *how* to return `application/xml` data.